# Remove previous dynamically added class

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I'm using this snippet to add a class based on its id:

```
   $('.block').click(function() {
     $('#bg').addClass($(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

but need to remove the last added class if one has been added as its causing problems when clicking previously clicked buttons as the current (higher) class overides lower, how can this be achieved?

[JFiddle for better understanding](http://jsfiddle.net/neAcr/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use removeClass to clear the div first.

```
$('.block').click(function() {
 $('#bg').removeClass().addClass($(this).attr('id'));
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/neAcr/3/)**

Comment: Marked as answer as its correct based on the question I asked but will use undefined's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `attr` method:

```
$('.block').click(function() {
    $('#bg').attr('class', this.id);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neAcr/4/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to do something like this

```
$('.block').click(function() {
$('#bg').removeClass()
$('#bg').addClass($(this).attr('id'));    
});​
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/neAcr/5/)